# Ionic build android doesn't find Android AVD

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an issue when I want to run the following command `sudo ionic cordova run android --device` but I have the error below.

[image]

Do Someone knows how I can fix it please? I have the avd folder in `~/.android`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok Found it, it's because I'm using `sudo`. Just `ionic cordova build android --device` is working